# G++ Unused Label Warning for Preprocessor Macro

Tags: c++

I'm working through compiler warnings in a project, attempting to clean up the code, and one warning/error that has confused me is an `unused-label` warning for the following code.

```cpp
STATE(initialize)
```

It says that the "initialize" label is defined but not used. `STATE` is a `#define` macro that is as follows:

```cpp
#define STATE(x)    x: __TRACE__("enter", #x);
```

And the `__TRACE__` macro is as follows:

```cpp
#define __TRACE__(y,x) dbg.printf(DebugIO::debug2,"FSM:" y "(" x ")\n");
```

Note, I did not write this code, and am just working through a project attempting to correct as many warnings as possible. But from what I can tell, the `initialize` label is passed to `__TRACE__` where it's used as an argument for a `printf()` call.

So, why is it not used? Does the compiler not look at preprocessor directives for variable usage?

How would I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from what I can tell, the `initialize` label is passed to `__TRACE__` where it's used as an argument for a `printf()` call.

No, it is not, actually.  The `x` parameter of `STATE()` is not the same as the `x` parameter of `__TRACE__()`.

In the statement `STATE(initialize)`, the `x` parameter is `initialize`, so `x:` becomes simply `initialize:` (the label in question), but `#x` stringifies the input value of `x` as `"initialize"` in this case, so `STATE(initialize)` expands to this:

```cpp
initialize: __TRACE__("enter", "initialize");
```

And then, in the `__TRACE__` macro, the `y` parameter is `"enter"` and the `x` parameter is `"initialize"`, so `__TRACE__("enter", "initialize")` expands to this:

```cpp
dbg.printf(DebugIO::debug2,"FSM:" "enter" "(" "initialize" ")\n");
```

And lastly, string literals that are separated by only whitespace are merged together by the compiler, so the final code for `STATE(initialize)` looks like this:

```cpp
initialize: dbg.printf(DebugIO::debug2,"FSM:enter(initialize)\n");;
```

And since there is no `goto` or other statement that references the `initialize` label, that is why you get a warning about it.

> How would I correct this?

Unless there is an actual `goto initialize` statement in the code somewhere, I would just get rid of the label altogether:

```cpp
#define STATE(x)    __TRACE__("enter", #x);
```

Comment: Ah, I was wondering what the # operator does in this context, since I don't use pre-processor directives much. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: On closer inspection, there IS a GOTO right before the STATE() call that is calling goto on the initialize label. Not sure if this would break things.

Comment: Then, in that case, the label would not be unused, and the compiler should not be complaining about it. Sounds like a compiler bug.

Comment: In any case, I asked a senior member of my team and they said not to touch the FSM code and just suppress the warning.

Answer (score 1):

The very reason for the warning is the fact that

```
x: TRACE...
```

introduces the label to be used with `goto`. It bears to reason that there is no `goto` to initialize state (it looks like we are looking at FSM implementation).

There is probably no way to remove this warning without re-working the framework (for example, adding a special state macro which does not define a label for states you never get into), but one can also just silence this particular warning for the project.

Comment: Yes, it is an FSM implementation, and yes, there is a GOTO call right before STATE that references the initialize label. Is there a way I can suppress just this instance of "unused label" without suppressing other instances?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `__attribute__((unused))` can be used [on a label](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Label-Attributes.html).

Converting the macro argument to a string doesn't count as "using" the label that happens to have the same name (remember that labels are a separate namespace from variables anyway, let alone macro arguments).

Using the (GCC extension) unary `&&` operator to take the address of the label might also suppress the warning, but as a rule you should avoid anything that looks like a dynamic `goto` unless you really know what you're doing. So prefer the attribute version.

---

Note also that `__TRACE__` is a reserved name since it contains 2 underscores next to each other.

Comment: Can also use `[[maybe_unused]]`. MSVC doesn't accept it for some reason, but GCC and Clang do.